# Nodejs listen for global hotkey press

Tags: node.js

I'm not using Node as a server; I'm using it for CLI apps. This one though needs to run in the background and listen for global key press events (without having focus).

I don't see any obvious way of doing this in Node. What are my options?

Comment: given that you're using it for command line tool purposes, what do mean with "in the background"; In the background of what?

Comment: Most of my apps are CLI apps. This one isn't really. It'll be a background process. But when you press its hotkey it'll popup a CLI interface.

Comment: right, so background of what? You run it as a background process, but what is your global environment? windows, OSX, Linux GUI, terminal access, a VM...?

Comment: Why should that matter? It should be cross platform. Windows, Linux, Mac too if possible.

Comment: What an odd question. Why *wouldn't* it matter? Different environments have different APIs for talking to the OS, and the chances that someone wrote a hotkey library for a specific OS is much higher than that someone wrote a library for all of them. I don't see anything like what you're asking about on http://npmjs.org, if you already looked there: it'll help if you update your post with what you've already looked for and where.

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar - I haven't verified this answer, but it looks like it might be what you were looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26734577/3212415

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you need global hook for all keyboard events.
You can try [iohook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iohook) module. Using is pretty simple:

```
const ioHook = require('iohook');
ioHook.on("keypress", event => {
  console.log(event);
  // {keychar: 'f', keycode: 19, rawcode: 15, type: 'keypress'}
});
ioHook.start();
```

Comment: Does not seem iohook will install for newer versions of Node.  I'm on Node v8.1.4 and it won't install, and I can't compile because the `npm install` doesn't leave any artifacts after failing the installation.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I just don't have a time for update iohook

Comment: @Steverino I already update iohook for support new versions of node.js

Comment: I am on v6.11.1 and can get only one keypress event.

Comment: Be careful! This lib has a bug. You cant open two instances of 'iohook' because you mouse freezes. Look it at https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook/issues/93

Comment: iohook doesn't prevent the shortcut from propagating, so, for example, I cannot set "Ctrl-Q" as a global shortcut, because it would close some windows.

Comment: THIS IS BUGGY. USE KEYPRESS https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress INSTEAD.

Answer (score 3):

I just do it with iohook. You could do something like this...

```
const ioHook = require('./node_modules/iohook-master/index.js');

ioHook.on("keyup",function(keyPress){
    if(keyPress.keycode == CTRLIZQ){
        //do something
    }
});

ioHook.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a combination of [daemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/daemon) and [keypress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypress) could do you want. I've only ever used keypress in a node script, not a daemon, so I have no idea if it will work the same way. But it might! At the very worst, you'll discover one solution that *doesn't* solve your problem.

Comment: can't believe this is working 8 years later 

Answer (score 1):

I said use `keypress` in a comment above, but seeing the lib is 8 years old and abandoned, [someone wrote](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress/issues/28#issue-643283219) the following as a replacement of the lib, it just does exactly the same thing, and yet it's a nodejs internal dependency.

```
let readline = require('readline');

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);

process.stdin.on('keypress', (ch, key) => {
  console.log('got "keypress"', ch, key);
  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
    console.log('ctrl+c was pressed');
    // do something usefull
  }
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.resume();
```

Comment: This does not listen to global keypresses though, only the current process if it is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

I tried ioHook, But it was not working, I guess because of the mac m1 chip.

I found another package, It is working as expected: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gkm

I also found one simple app, you can run on the terminal: https://github.com/KleoPetroff/node-global-key-listener

Answer (score 0):

gkm works on Linux

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gkm

```
const gkm = require('gkm');

gkm.events.on('key.*', data => {
    const button = data[0];

    if (button === 'Escape') {
        console.log('Escaped');
        process.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: It does work indeed, but requires Java to be installed.