# How do I detect whether a key is pressed in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a little utility written in node.js that does some real-time data capture. I'd like to augment it so it also records whether a particular key is pressed on the keyboard at which time during the capture. (This allows me to "mark" the time in the data capture when some event happened).

But how do I detect whether a given key is pressed/down on the keyboard from node.js? Something like readline won't work because it's line-based, and waits until CR is entered. (The capture needs to continue in real time.) Instead, it needs to access the keyboard on a fairly low level to get "the state of key X right now", returning pressed or not-pressed.

Is there such a thing in node.js?

Comment: As this amounts to a "find-the-npm-package" request, this question is [off-topic (#4)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs listen for global hotkey press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883037/nodejs-listen-for-global-hotkey-press)

Answer (score 3):

Just use [iohook npm module](https://github.com/WilixLead/iohook). 
This is example:

```
const iohook = require('iohook');
iohook.on("keypress", event => {
  console.log(event);
  // {keychar: 'f', keycode: 19, rawcode: 15, type: 'keypress'}
});
iohook.start();
```

But this is question is duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883037/nodejs-listen-for-global-hotkey-press/41441872#41441872)

Comment: Looks like this module has been abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress/issues/28#issue-643283219) ;

```
let readline = require('readline');

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);

process.stdin.on('keypress', (ch, key) => {
  console.log('got "keypress"', ch, key);
  if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
    process.stdin.pause();
  }
});

process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
```

Comment: perfect! no dependencies, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`iohook` support only nodejs v8.x - v15.x

`readline` support current nodejs v19.x

Try install readline with command: `npm I readline`

```
var readline = require('readline');

readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);

if (process.stdin.isTTY)
    process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

console.log('press q to exit, or any key to print log');

process.stdin.on('keypress', (chunk, key) => {
  if (key && key.name == 'q'){
    process.exit();
  }
  console.log({key});
});
```