# nodejs program detect keypress event on terminal lost focus

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm developing a small node js program that consists on a list of copies (ctrl+c) and then paste it (ctrl+v) secuentially. I run the program on terminal, and it work fine. The problem is when this terminal lost the focus. When it occurs, the program can't detect keypress events, so I cant "save" the selected text when key combination is pressed.

The project is here if you want see the code (main.js).

https://github.com/athos54/advancedcopypaste

Thanks very much

Comment: do you mean when the terminal lost focus and is focused again? Because if not focused again, it is normal not to trigger the keypressed events.

Comment: So you want your program to run in the background and save all things copied to the clipboard? I don't believe node is the right tool here

Comment: Like Shizzle say, I have done it with iohook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that iohook may be the tool you're looking for.
Check out this answer from Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441872/4932490

Answer (score 0):

I have done with iohook, I have had problems installing iohook npm package on linux mint and macos, but I have been able to compile the module and it work fine now, thanks very much.